# Downloading data/content into Sqlite database

Tags: android, json, sqlite

I want users to be able to get additional content from my website which means I will insert the downloaded data into the device's SQLite. I am wondering if I am approaching this the right way..

My current approach is to create a REST web service which returns data in JSON format, parse the JSON and insert it row by row into the Sqlite db on the android device.

Is this the right approach? Will it be too slow if there are many table rows to be inserted at one time? Or is there a way to download another SQlite db and merge it with the local one?

I welcome any suggestion, thank you in advance for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I works, but you absolutely need to paginate : set a limit to the number of element sent by your rest service.

Another approach would be to download the complete sqlite database file at once, but that requires some tweaks. see http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/ (it is about embeding the database from the assets, but the preparation of the database is the same.)

A last point: large amount of insert, as well as downloading data from a server, must to be done in a separate thread or asynctask, from a service (not an activity that can be interrupted), or even better from a SynchronizationAdapter, which is called by the system itself.

Comment: Hi njzk2, thanks for your answer. I use reigndesign's approach for my initial database, but this downloading of data is for the cases where the user wants more content for the app. Basically I'm looking for the most efficient approach to insert more data into the existing db.

Comment: what quantity of rows are we talking about? hundreds? thousands?

Comment: In the hundreds I would think (200-300). But I also plan to download related image files for those hundreds (just a small image each).

Comment: if the image is small enough, a blob in the sqlite db is fine. else, you will need to put it in a separated file. (i have no idea what size "small enough" would be. a few Ko, i guess)

Comment: Thanks for the input. The audio files that come with the original .apk are all in the raw folder. Do you think this is not the right place to put hundreds of audio files? If not, I guess I could try to put them into the db. They are in the 10-50 Kb each.

Comment: if the audio files can be bundled with the application, i think the raw folder is the right place.