# How to scrape Facebook friends' info INCLUDING their real e-mail the way Facebook App does?

Tags: facebook

I recently found that Facebook App (for Android & iOS, but i'm using Android anyway) downloads almost all friends' information (including FB ID and **real e-mail** account) to a `SQLite` database called fb.db. I am trying to do the same thing programmaticaly (using python, perl, bash etc) but with no luck so far. I need a way that will do similar requests with FB APP, and will download all of my friends' info **upon login**, just like the way FB APP work.

I tried so far to:

1. Decompile `com.facebook.katana` and see how it's done - No luck (or just missed it).
2. Sniff the facebook app with burp - No luck (due to `SSL` and app's protection when certs have been changed)

Answer (score 2):

I am sure you went through this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db

There it is stated:

> Android provides full support for SQLite databases. Any databases you create will be accessible by name to any class in the application, but not outside the application.

It was not the answer, it was just a text, which states that you can create a database for your web app. But unfortunately they are not providing any kind of helping material about writing and removing the data from that Database. So lets move to another source!

**Related posts:**

Please read this:

[How to insert data into SQLite database in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11019924/how-to-insert-data-into-sqlite-database-in-android)

There is a sweet example of how to add the content to a database in Android.

There is another example on this question too, [Downloading data/content into Sqlite database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7257627/downloading-data-content-into-sqlite-database)

**Why they didn't work:**

Decompiling won't work! As they might have editted the app to be only fb-developer-readable on the first place. So you will never have success this way.

And the second thing is same.

All you can do, is to guess the algorithm or ask for it here: http://programmers.stackexchange.com and give it a try from scratch! :)

**Suggestions:**

I would try to recommend you to first learn how to:

1. Access Data connection on the phone.
2. Access the server from where to download the data.
3. Create a string or what ever data type to be inserted in database.
4. Create the connection, and save the data there!

I would now assume that you are a beginner, and want a tutorial! Then the first guess could be to visit their own project sites (SQLite, Android). Visit the developer network. And look for what you get!

Good luck buddy! Cheers.

Comment: This is super helpful but not what i am trying to achieve. I am trying to do it out-of-android, completely third party stuff. My question was how can i download my own friends' REAL emails (as many as i am allowed to see) programmatically just like the way the Facebook APP does! Thanks again!